# General Guidline in making a index for a textbook

Tags: mathematics, writing, books

I am currently writing a textbook in some mathematical area and now I am at the point of creating an index of words.

Are there some general rules in academia on this, like there are for citing references?

For example, if I have some mathematical theorem, like "Theorem of BlaBla", should I then include it to "T" or to "B"? And also if there is some general definition, like a "norm" of a space and then there are some specific examples, like "p-norms", should I then order the latter separately in $p$ or together wth the general concept at "n"?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/indices

Comment: I know how to make an index with latex thats not the problem. I am asking if there are some general rules for making them.

Comment: I don't think there are general rules. My experience is many of them are a mess. Personally I'd have an entry under both "T" and "B" for the "Theorem of BlaBla" because some readers may look in one place and others in the other one. I think asking yourself what is most reader-friendly is a good guideline.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot @Lewian !

Comment: @Udalricu S Your question is specifically about mathematics and I don't have an answer.  Wiley publishes many technical books.  They have a detailed and excellent guide to indexing that might be useful.  https://authorservices.wiley.com/author-resources/book-authors/prepare-your-manuscript/indexing.html